# Image is not displaying using TCPDF

Tags: php, html, mysqli, tcpdf, cakephp-3.1

I am working in CakePHP 3 application. Here I am using TCPDF for PDF Generation. Everything works fine except image. Image is not displaying.

Here my `pdf()` action file:

```
public function pdf()
    {
    $this->loadModel('Users');
    $users=$this->Users->find('all')->select(['firstname','lastname','email','image_path']);
    $this->set(compact('users'));
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('pdf');
    }
```

My pdf.ctp file :

```
$html = '<table>';

foreach($users as $users) {
  $html .= '<tr>
  <td>' . $users['firstname'] . '</td>
  <td>' . $users['lastname'] . '</td>
  <td>' . $users['email'] . '</td>
  <td><img src="/sample/webroot/img/'.$users['image_path'].'"/></td> 
        </tr>';    
}
$html .= '</table>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Can any one help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: The `src=""` should use an absolute path to your image file such as `/www/mywebsite.com/images/puppies.jpg`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus. If I specified image file name directly means, it is displaying, like <td><img src="/sample/webroot/img/hmueegqsxy3n3rab3t69.jpg"/></td> . But When I specified like above means it is not showing

Comment: Are you positive it exists?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it exists

Comment: Do some debugging, check what exactly the dynamically generated path looks like, if the hardcoded one works, then the dynamic one must obviously be different.

Comment: @ndm still it is not displaying images.

Comment: How can "_it still doesn't work_" be an "answer" to my suggestion to do some debugging?

Comment: @ndm. Thanks. I find out the problem and now working fine.

Comment: How did you find out? Please write an answer then.